# Query history only today

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Question: The queryhistory() function seems to return the queries of today, and not of the last 7 days as the documentations says. LIMIT set to 10000, but no luck.

SELECT DATABASE_NAME, QUERY_TYPE, USER_NAME, START_TIME, EXECUTION_TIME
FROM TABLE(information_schema.query_history(RESULT_LIMIT => 10000))

Now looking at the Snowflake DB view Query history, but is seems like the DB is generated somehow for the account. A turning wheel is running for hours, now.

Anyone an idea how to retrieve queries of the last 7 days?

Hennie

Comment: RESULT_LIMIT supports up to 10K max, not above. Even so, under what user/role are you executing this? **query_history** returns queries run by the current user. Also returns queries run by any user when the executing role, or a higher role in a hierarchy, has the MONITOR privilege on the warehouse.

Comment: More Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html#usage-notes

Answer (score 0):

Using [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html) view:

```
SELECT * 
FROM snowflake.account_usage.QUERY_HISTORY 
WHERE START_TIME >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, CURRENT_DATE())
```